# JsonWriter.close() closes Socket?

Tags: json, sockets, java-8

When I close a `JsonWriter`, does it close the socket too? Because I don't want that. I want the server to keep the connection so I can send commands to it. like the one (command) I'm currently coding is "getplayers". The client sends an object with that text (String) "getplayers". Then the server switches between the commands and does whatever command the client sends. If my `JsonWriter`, which sends the `playerList`, closes the socket after it finishes "getplayers", but that's not what I want.

Server Code:

```
switch (command) {
    case "getplayers":
        qryFullPlayerTable = mySQLConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT pid,uuid,nickname,firstjoined,lastquit FROM PlayerList");
        result = qryFullPlayerTable.executeQuery();

        clientHandlerOut.writeObject("getplayers");

        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientHandlerOut));
        resultSetToJsonArrayStream(result, jsonWriter);
        jsonWriter.close();
```

Client Code (I know it doesn't work like this - read data it doesn't show properly in the textField, but something is closing the connection and that's what I don't want to happen first):

```
switch(command) {
    case "getplayers": 
      /*while((obj2=in.readObject()) != null) {
            currentFromServer = obj2.toString().toLowerCase();

            if (currentFromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                consoleOneTextArea.appendText("This is finished. Have fun!\n");
                break;
            }

            consoleOneTextArea.appendText(currentFromServer + "\n");
      */JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

        try {
            while(jsonReader.hasNext()){
                JsonToken nextToken = jsonReader.peek();
                System.out.println(nextToken);

                if(JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT.equals(nextToken)){

                jsonReader.beginObject();

                } else if(JsonToken.NAME.equals(nextToken)){
                    String name  =  jsonReader.nextName();

                    switch(name) {
                        case "pid":
                            System.out.println("pid: " + jsonReader.nextInt());
                        default:
                            System.out.println("TODO: " + name);
                    }
                }

        jsonReader.close();

        break;
```

Where the client checks a TextField for the command and if it's "getplayers" it sends "getplayers" to the server. Other way around, the server just listens for a command, and sends the playerdata. It is a clientHandler and so it should stay connected until the client disconnects.

The errors I get - on server:

> [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1286)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1231)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1577)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   de.freakyonline.uconeplugin.UCOnePluginServer$ClientHandler.run(UCOnePluginServer.java:112)
>   [16:04:56] [Thread-10/WARN]:    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

on client:

> java.net.SocketException: socket closed   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2321)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2614)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
>     at de.freakyonline.ucone.Remote.run(Remote.java:53)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Is there a possibility to prevent `jsonWriter.close()` to close the socket? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you `close()` a `JsonWriter`, the underlying socket also gets closed.

To avoid the socket being closed, just don't close the writer, and let it be garbage collected instead. Though you may want to make sure that everything is `flush()`'d.

The purpose of the `close()` is to flush any buffer and free any underlying resources (output streams, file handles, sockets, ...), but since you explicitly don't want that, you don't need to do it.